# How to develop in Linux using GNU toolchain, coming from Java?

Tags: linux, build, dependencies, autotools

I'm a good Java programmer, albeit the first languages I learnt were C/C++. Anyway, for work reasons, I switched to Java and web languages. Sometimes I get interested in this or that Linux project, usually coming as a git or svn repository... The problem is that I usually clone the repo, I try to configure it, I install all the needed libraries (and this takes ages), maybe finally I succeed... but then make fails or configure itself fails, complaining about some tool that is missing. Or maybe I installed two versions of the same library and the configure script gets the wrong one, or boring problems like this. 
Anyway, I see loads of people using those tools everyday, so it must not be so difficult after all!

Can you point out resources that may help in the first steps?

Thanks

Comment: Installing the needed libraries should not take ages; learn to use your Linux distro's package manager. Usually, headers are in packages named `*-dev` or `*-devel`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to are known as **autotools** and **make**

autotools are used to generate scripts and build files that can be used to build as well as install a program/package/software (whatever you call it)

Here is [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) for the GNU build system in general.

And refer to [this link](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html) for details about the autotools and related stuff

Answer (score 0):

It may take longer, but if you are interested in how to fix those problems yourself I recommend learning how autoconf and automake work. I made a positive experience with the book "Autotools: a practitioner's guide to Autoconf, Automake and Libtool". I read the dead-tree version but it is also available online: http://fsmsh.com/2753.